# Retrieving data in status of active with a wild card criteria (Mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have problem retrieving data in database.

Question: Why I still retrieve the data of having store_status **DELETED** but my condition is store_status = 'Active' only

This is my script look like

```
SELECT * FROM store_locator WHERE store_status = 'Active' AND store_address LIKE '%Q%' 
OR branch_name LIKE '%Q%' OR city LIKE '%Q%'
```

And the sample image
[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPMDZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's likely happening because either your branch_name has a Q in it or the city has a Q in it.
The OR conditions ensure that records can still be shown even though the AND conditions are false.
Your query is essentially running this:

```
SELECT *
FROM store_locator
WHERE (store_status = 'Active'
  AND store_address LIKE '%Q%')
OR (branch_name LIKE '%Q%')
OR (city LIKE '%Q%')
```

So if **any of these conditions are true**, the record will be shown:

- store_status = 'Active' AND store_address LIKE '%Q%'
- branch_name LIKE '%Q%'
- city LIKE '%Q%'

If this is not the logic you wanted, then you can adjust your query to include brackets () around the AND/OR criteria that you want to use. If you only want to see active records where any of those fields have a Q in it, you may want this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM store_locator
WHERE store_status = 'Active'
AND (store_address LIKE '%Q%'
OR branch_name LIKE '%Q%'
OR city LIKE '%Q%')
```

Note that the brackets have enclosed all of the three LIKE '%Q%' criteria in a single condition.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you didn't group your `OR` condition,

IMO this should be your right query to use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM store_locator 
WHERE store_status = 'Active' 
    AND (store_address LIKE '%Q%' OR branch_name LIKE '%Q%' OR city LIKE '%Q%');
```